# accessing a protected member of a base class in another subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, encapsulation, protected

Why does this compile:

```
class FooBase
{
protected:
    void fooBase(void);
};

class Foo : public FooBase
{
public:
    void foo(Foo& fooBar)
    {
        fooBar.fooBase();
    }
};
```

but this does not?

```
class FooBase
{
protected:
    void fooBase(void);
};

class Foo : public FooBase
{
public:
    void foo(FooBase& fooBar)
    {
        fooBar.fooBase();
    }
};
```

On the one hand C++ grants access to private/protected members for all instances of that class, but on the other hand it does not grant access to protected members of a base class for all instances of a subclass.
This looks rather inconsistent to me.

I have tested compiling with VC++ and with ideone.com and both compile the first but not the second code snippet.

Comment: @iammilind are you sure you are closing the correct question? Or should it be the other way around?

Comment: @Eiko originally I closed the other one with this first. Then I found that answer present there was more elaborate and quoted with standard. Hence reopened that and closed this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When `foo` receives a `FooBase` reference, the compiler doesn't know whether the argument is a descendant of `Foo`, so it has to assume it's not. `Foo` has access to inherited protected members of *other `Foo` objects*, not all other sibling classes.

Consider this code:

```
class FooSibling: public FooBase { };

FooSibling sib;
Foo f;
f.foo(sib); // calls sib.fooBase()!?
```

If `Foo::foo` can call protected members of arbitrary `FooBase` descendants, then it can call the protected method of `FooSibling`, which has no direct relationship to `Foo`. That's not how protected access is supposed to work.

If `Foo` needs access to protected members of all `FooBase` objects, not just those that are also known to be `Foo` descendants, then `Foo` needs to be a friend of `FooBase`:

```
class FooBase
{
protected:
  void fooBase(void);
  friend class Foo;
};
```

Comment: Ah, with your example code the reason, why it isn't allowed, is pretty obvious. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get your exemple. If fooBase is not virtual, what you get is FooBase::fooBase, which is what you indicate anyway. If fooBase is virtual, you're in fact calling FooSibling::fooBase, but it's also the reason why you're using virtual functions: to be able to adapt the functions to the actual object ? I don't see when this behavious is a problem.

Comment: Virtual is irrelevant here, @Vincent. A member's virtual status doesn't affect who's allowed to use its name. The member's *visibility* is what determines who can use its name. `Foo` can see protected members of other known `Foo` objects. It cannot see protected members of any other object, not even those related to its ancestor classes, because those ancestors aren't necessary *known* to be `Foo`. Virtuality and visibility are orthogonal concepts in C++ (but not necessarily in other languages).

Comment: @RobKennedy I understand that, I just can't see any real example in which one would need to prevent a derived class from accessing a protected member/function from another instance of the base class, be it virtual or not,.

Answer (score 21):

The [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/classes-and-objects#directly-access-private-in-other-instances) summarizes this issue nicely:

> [You] are allowed to pick your own pockets, but you are not allowed to pick your father's pockets nor your brother's pockets.

Comment: you are allowed to pick your own as well as your son's pockets

Answer (score 12):

The key point is that `protected` grants you access to your own copy of the member, not to those members in *any* other object. This is a common misconception, as more often than not we generalize and state `protected` grants access to the member to the derived type (without explicitly stating that only to their own bases...)

Now, that is for a reason, and in general you should not access the member in a different branch of the hierarchy, as you might break the invariants on which other objects depend. Consider a type that performs an expensive calculation on some large data member (protected) and two derived types that caches the result following different strategies:

```
class base {
protected:
   LargeData data;
// ...
public:
   virtual int result() const;      // expensive calculation
   virtual void modify();           // modifies data
};
class cache_on_read : base {
private:
   mutable bool cached;
   mutable int cache_value;
// ...
   virtual int result() const {
       if (cached) return cache_value;
       cache_value = base::result();
       cached = true;
   }
   virtual void modify() {
       cached = false;
       base::modify();
   }
};
class cache_on_write : base {
   int result_value;
   virtual int result() const {
      return result_value;
   }
   virtual void modify() {
      base::modify();
      result_value = base::result(); 
   }
};
```

The `cache_on_read` type captures modifications to the data and marks the result as invalid, so that the next *read* of the value recalculates. This is a good approach if the number of writes is relatively high, as we only perform the calculation on demand (i.e. multiple modifies will not trigger recalculations). The `cache_on_write` precalculates the result upfront, which might be a good strategy if the number of writes is small, and you want deterministic costs for the read (think low latency on reads).

Now, back to the original problem. Both cache strategies maintain a stricter set of invariants than the base. In the first case, the extra invariant is that `cached` is `true` only if `data` has not been modified after the last read. In the second case, the extra invariant is that `result_value` is the value of the operation at all times.

If a third derived type took a reference to a `base` and accessed `data` to write (if `protected` allowed it to), then it would break with the invariants of the derived types.

That being said, the specification of the language is *broken* (personal opinion) as it leaves a backdoor to achieve that particular result. In particular, if you create a pointer to member of a member from a base in a derived type, access is checked in `derived`, but the returned pointer is a pointer to member of `base`, which can be applied to *any* `base` object:

```
class base {
protected:
   int x;
};
struct derived : base {
   static void modify( base& b ) {
      // b.x = 5;                        // error!
      b.*(&derived::x) = 5;              // allowed ?!?!?!
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In both examples `Foo` inherits a protected method `fooBase`. However, in your first example you try to access the given protected method from the same class (`Foo::foo` calls `Foo::fooBase`), while in the second example you try to access a protected method from another class which isn't declared as friend class (`Foo::foo` tries to call `FooBase::fooBase`, which fails, the later is protected).

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you pass an object of type Foo, which obviously inherits the method fooBase() and so is able to call it. In the second example you are trying to call a protected function, simply so, regardless in which context you can't call a protected function from a class instance where its declared so.
In the first example you inherit the protected method fooBase, and so you have the right to call it WITHIN Foo context

Answer (score 1):

I tend to see things in terms of concepts and messages. If your FooBase method was actually called "SendMessage" and Foo was "EnglishSpeakingPerson" and FooBase was SpeakingPerson, your *protected* declaration is intended to restrict SendMessage to between EnglishSpeakingPersons (and subclasses eg: AmericanEnglishSpeakingPerson, AustralianEnglishSpeakingPerson) . Another type FrenchSpeakingPerson derived from SpeakingPerson would not be able to receive a SendMessage, unless you declared the FrenchSpeakingPerson as a friend, where 'friend' meant that the FrenchSpeakingPerson has a special ability to receive SendMessage from EnglishSpeakingPerson (ie can understand English).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [hobo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14154903/40916) you may seek a workaround.

If you want the subclasses to want to call the `fooBase` method you can make it `static`. static protected methods are accessible by subclasses with all arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around without a friend like so...

```html
class FooBase
{
protected:
    void fooBase(void);
    static void fooBase(FooBase *pFooBase) { pFooBase->fooBase(); }
};
```

This avoids having to add derived types to the base class. Which seems a bit circular.