# Policy inheritance and inaccessible protected members

Tags: c++, inheritance, visibility, protected, policy

It seems that a protected member from a template policy class is inaccessible, even with a class hierarchy which seems correct.

For instance, with the following code snippet :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class A {
  protected:
    T value;
    T getValue() { return value; }
  public:
    A(T value) { this->value = value; }
};

template <class T, template <class U> class A>
class B : protected A<T> {
  public:
    B() : A<T>(0) { /* Fake value */ }
    void print(A<T>& input) {
      cout << input.getValue() << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  B<int, A> b;
  A<int> a(42);
  b.print(a);
}
```

The compiler (clang on OS X, but gcc returns the same type of error) returns the following error :

```
Untitled.cpp:18:21: error: 'getValue' is a protected member of 'A<int>'
      cout << input.getValue() << endl;
                ^
Untitled.cpp:25:5: note: in instantiation of member function 'B<int, A>::print' requested here
  b.print(a);
    ^
Untitled.cpp:8:7: note: can only access this member on an object of type 'B<int, A>'
    T getValue() { return value; }
      ^
1 error generated.
```

The strange thing is that the last note from the compiler is totally correct but already applied since the `b` object is of type `'B<int, A>'`. Is that a compiler bug or is there a problem in the code ?

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631777/accessing-a-protected-member-of-a-base-class-in-another-subclass for the answer to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's forget for a minute about the template and look at this:

```
 class A {
   protected:
     int value;
     int getValue() { return value; }
   public:
     A(int value) { this->value = value; }
 };

 class B : protected A {
   public:
     B() : A(0) { /* Fake value */ }
     void print(A& input) {
       cout << input.getValue() << endl;
     }
 };
```

The `print()` method's implementation is wrong because **you can't access non-public member of `A` inside `B`.** And here's why: from within `B`, you can only access non-public members of `B`. Those members may be either inherited or not — it doesn't matter.

On the other hand, `A& input` may not be a reference to an instance of `B`. It may be a reference to another subclass (which may well have `getValue()` inaccessible).

Comment: "You can't access non-public member of A inside B."
Yes you can. As long as B is derived from A you can access protected members of class A, but only within class A.

Comment: @DavidJensen I believe what you're saying is what shakurov means by *inside B* (i.e., corresponding to your mentioning "only within class A").

Comment: Yes but still then he is saying that they cant be accessed and i am saying that that can.

Comment: @DavidJensen I read that sentence to mean "*you can't access non-public member of an explicit A object inside B*" - is that how you're reading it?

Answer (score 10):

You have misunderstood the meaning of protected access.

Protected members are callable by derived classes. But only on the base object contained inside the class itself.

For example, if i simplify the problem, using :

```
class A {
protected:
    void getValue(){}
};

class B : protected A
{
public:
    void print(A& input)
    {
        input.getValue(); //Invallid
    }
};
```

getValue cannot be called on a "A" object other than the "A" object inside the class itself.
This for example is valid.

```
    void print()
    {
        getValue(); //Valid, calling the base class getValue()
    }
```

As pointed out by Dan Nissenbaum and shakurov. This is however also valid:

```
void print(B& input)
{
    input.getValue();
}
```

This is because we explicitly say that input is a object of B. And the compiler know that all that objects of B has protected access to getValue. In the case when we pass a A&, the object might as-well be a type of C, wich could be derrived from A with private access.

Comment: However, by changing the signature to `void print(B& input)` (i.e., pass a `B` object, rather than an `A` object) - it's legal.  (Note: assuming `getValue()` returns something valid, not `void`).

Comment: Because encapsulation is class-based and not object-based. Otherwise writing assignment operators would've been a nightmare.

Comment: I think the answer is given by @shakurov when he writes **A& input may not be a reference to an instance of B. It may be a reference to another subclass (which may well have getValue() inaccessible**.  Because of this, only actual explicit `B` class objects allow access to their protected members.

Comment: I think this answer would be technically correct if the sentence "But only on the base object contained inside the class itself" were removed.

Answer (score 3):

Member functions of a derived class have access to protected base class members within any object of its type that is passed as an argument **so long as the explicitly declared class of the object passed as an argument is that of the the derived class** (or a further derived class).

Objects explicitly passed as the **base** class type cannot have their protected members accessed within the derived class's member functions.

In other words, if we have:

```
class A
{
protected:
    int x;
}

class B : public A
{
    void foo(B b)
    {
        b.x; // allowed because 'b' is explicitly declared as an object of class B
    }
    void goo(A a)
    {
        a.x; // error because 'a' is explicitly declared as having *base* class type
    }
};
```

...then the line `a.x` is not allowed because the explicit type of the argument is `A`, but the rule for protected access only applies to objects explicitly defined as the **same** class as the class attempting to access the member.  (...Or a class derived from it; i.e., if `class C`derives from `B`, then passing an object explicitly declared as an object of class `C` will also have `x` accessible within `B` member functions.)

The reason for this is given by shakurov when he writes (paraphrasing)

> A& input might not be a reference to an instance of B. It may be a
>   reference to another subclass (which may well have getValue()
>   inaccessible)

An excellent explication of this answer is also given here: [accessing a protected member of a base class in another subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631777/accessing-a-protected-member-of-a-base-class-in-another-subclass).

As a matter of interest, I believe that this comes from the C++ standard here:

> 11.4 Protected member access [class.protected] 1 An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause 11 is applied when a
>   non-static data member or non-static member function is a protected
>   member of its naming class (11.2)115 As described earlier, access to a
>   protected member is granted because the reference occurs in a friend
>   or member of some class C. If the access is to form a pointer to
>   member (5.3.1), the nested-name-specifier shall denote C or a class
>   derived from C. All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit)
>   object expression (5.2.5). In this case, the class of the object
>   expression shall be C or a class derived from C.

Answer (score 2):

Don't get distracted by the template. It has nothing to do with the error. The line in `main` that the compiler is complaining about creates an object of type `B<int, a>` and tries to access a protected member. That's not legal, regardless of the type. You can only use protected members from **inside** a member function or friend function. For example:

```
struct S {
protected:
    void f();
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.f(); // error: attempts to call a protected member function
}
```