# Why can a derived class not access a protected member of its base class through a pointer to base?

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope, protected

This is the [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04f05e3845e6ccea):

```
class TestA
{
protected:
    int test=12;

public:
    TestA() {
        cout << "test a: " << test << endl;
    }
    ~TestA() {
    }
};

class TestB : public TestA
{   
public:
    TestB(TestA *testA) {
        cout << "test b: " << testA->test;
    }
    ~TestB() {
    }
};

int main ()
{
    TestA *pTestA=new TestA();
    TestB *pTestB=new TestB(pTestA);
}
```

I'm trying to access of a `protected` member using a pointer pointing to a `TestA` type object (thus, an instance of `TestA`). `TestB` is also derived from `TestA`

Why I can't access to it? Is it accessible only "within" the class where I need it? Not outside using pointer/direct declarations?

Comment: I am reopening this question as the answer mentioned here is better than the older duplicate: [accessing a protected member of a base class in another subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11631777/514235). Closing the other one.

Comment: Short answer: Because the standard says this is forbidden. Accordingly, standard compliant compilers will throw an error on it. YMMV, but I would actually call this a bug in the standard.

Comment: @cmaster (See the sample code in my answer) If it's allowed, it's possible to access the protected members through a pointer of type `B*` which points to an instance of `D1` in member function of `D2`. But `D1` and `D2` are irrelevant in fact. It seems counterintuitive.

Answer (score 8):

When public inherite from the base class, its protected members become **the derived class'** protect members, which could be accessed in derived class' member functions. But they could only be accessed through the **derived class itself** (and its derived classes), can't be accessed through the base class. So you can't access member `test` via pointer of `TestA`, but it'll be fine to access it via pointer of `TestB`.

The standard gives some illustrative samples for this. [[class.protected]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.protected#1):

(Only keep a part of the example code)

> An additional access check beyond those described earlier in Clause
>   [class.access] is applied when a non-static data member or non-static
>   member function is a protected member of its naming class
>   ([class.access.base])114 As described earlier, access to a protected
>   member is granted because the reference occurs in a friend or member
>   of some class C. If the access is to form a pointer to member
>   ([expr.unary.op]), the nested-name-specifier shall denote C or a class
>   derived from C. All other accesses involve a (possibly implicit)
>   object expression ([expr.ref]). In this case, the class of the object
>   expression shall be C or a class derived from C. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class B {
> protected:
>   int i;
> };
>
> class D1 : public B {
> };
>
> class D2 : public B {
>   void mem(B*,D1*);
> };
>
> void D2::mem(B* pb, D1* p1) {
>   pb->i = 1;                    // ill-formed
>   p1->i = 2;                    // ill-formed
>   i = 3;                        // OK (access through this)
>   B::i = 4;                     // OK (access through this, qualification ignored)
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

I'm not sure about your design's intent, making `TestB` friend of `TestA` would be a straightforward solution.

Comment: This is one of the harder-to-justify (for me) access rules.

Comment: By the way, "When public inherite from the base class,  its protected members become the derived class' protect members": Is that not true for protected inheritance as well? Or even private?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It's true for `protected inheritance` too, for `private inheritance`, will be "its protected members become the derived class' private members".

Answer (score 0):

Concept of accessibility of class members by WORLD is applicable here.
WORLD can access only public members of class irrespective of how they are created/derived.

Consider the example below:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int public_i;
    protected:
        int protected_i;
    private:
        int private_i;

    public:
        A()
        {
            public_i = 10;
            protected_i = 20;
            private_i = 30;
        }
};

class C : protected A
{
    public:
        void Access(void)
        {
            cout << public_i << endl;
            cout << protected_i << endl;
            //cout << private_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here
        }
};
class D : private A
{
    public:
        void Access(void)
        {
            cout << public_i << endl;
            cout << protected_i << endl;
            //cout << private_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here
        }
};
class B : public A
{
    public:
        void Access(D *pd)
        {
            cout << public_i << endl;
            cout << protected_i << endl;
            //cout << private_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here

            //pd is WORLD here
            //cout << pd->public_i << endl;    // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here since private inheritance of A by D
            //cout << pd->protected_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its protected here
            //cout << pd->private_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here
        }
};


int main ()
{
    A objA;
    cout << objA.public_i << endl;
    //cout << objA.protected_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its protected here
    //cout << objA.private_i << endl;   // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here

    B objB;
    cout << objB.public_i << endl;
    //cout << objB.protected_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its protected here
    //cout << objB.private_i << endl;   // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here

    C objC;
    //cout << objC.public_i << endl;    // <- Not Allowed b'coz its protected here
    //cout << objC.protected_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its protected here
    //cout << objC.private_i << endl;   // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here

    D objD;
    //cout << objD.public_i << endl;    // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here
    //cout << objD.protected_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its protected here
    //cout << objD.private_i << endl;   // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here

    //Outside class its all WORLD and WORLD can access only public members.
    //Objects and Pointers are WORLD.

    //Same thing is applicable when class members are accessed via pointers.
    B *pobjB;       //pobjB is WORLD
    cout << pobjB->public_i << endl;
    //cout << pobjB->protected_i << endl; // <- Not Allowed b'coz its protected here
    //cout << pobjB->private_i << endl;   // <- Not Allowed b'coz its private here

    objB.Access(&objD);
    objC.Access();
    objD.Access();

    return 0;
}
```