# Friend function and Inheritance in cpp

Tags: c++, function, friend

Am new to cpp. Generally, friend function could access private and protected members of the class but when I tried to use friend function in derived class am observing weired behavior..

```
class first
{
  int a;
};

class second : public first
{
  public:
   friend void hai ( second );
};

void hai ( second s )
{
 printf("%d",s.a); // It says compilation error 
}

void main()
{
  second s;
  hai(s);
}
```

If I make ***a to public***, it works fine.

Could somebody clear me, why shouldn't I access a if its in base private scope.

Regards
Prasath S.

Comment: int a; is not part of second class and has not inherited due to default private access specifier

Answer (score 0):

Make field `a` protected, not private.

Private fields can be accessed only from class declaring them.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
class first
{
  int a;
};
```

The default for class members is private so you won't have access to it from derived classes.

Private members are only accessible from the same class. The line

```
class second : public first
```

doesn't change the private member to public, so you have the choice between making `a` protected/public or you include a public/protected get/set function to `first`, which will manage the access to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

> why shouldn't I access a if its in base private scope.

`friend` function can access `private` members of the class that it friends to.

However in this case, member `a` in base class is `private` by default and therefore not inherited to child class.

Public inheritance requires `protected` or members of base class to be inherited by child classes. So for your example to work, you can use `protected` member `a`

```
class first
{
    protected:
        int a;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`first::a` is `private` in `class first`

`class second` is derived publicly from `class first`, so:

- all the public members of `class first` are public in `class second` and can be accessed via objects of `class second`.
- all the protected members of `class first` are protected in `class second` and cannot be accessed via objects of `class second`.
- all the private members of `class first` are inaccessible in `class second` and cannot be accessed via objects of `class second`.

Therefore, you cannot access `first::a` via object of `class second`.

For more information: [Can a friend class object access base class private members on a derived class object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384399/can-a-friend-class-object-access-base-class-private-members-on-a-derived-class-o/39386702#39386702)

[Why can a derived class not access a protected member of its base class through a pointer to base?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717447/why-can-a-derived-class-not-access-a-protected-member-of-its-base-class-through/38719990#38719990)